# Настроить OPEN VPN с защитой от утечек на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Подскажите, как настроить OPEN VPN с защитой от утечек на Ubuntu?

То есть чтобы если соединение порвалось или вдруг open vpn стал пропускать траф напрямую (на виндовс такое бывает), то сразу резался любой траф.

Comment: вы хотите настроить клиент OpenVPN или сервер?
Как-то не очень понятно - причем тут windows?

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите статические маршруты, удалите маршруты по умолчанию. Тогда при разрыве соединения трафик уйдет в "никуда". Лучше, если на сервере шлюзом будет машина с адресом вида 10. или 192.168.